# Is there a continuous transformation between $\cos x$ to $\cosh x$?

Tags: analytic-geometry, conic-sections, curves, projective-geometry, hyperbolic-functions

Gilbert Strang notes [a parabola is an intermediary between ellipses and hyperbola](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4515117/what-are-some-other-ways-in-which-a-parabola-is-between-an-ellipse-and-a-hyperb).  As discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3097564/how-does-a-parabola-sit-smoothly-between-cartesian-ellipse-and-hyperbola), this is easy to see in polar coordinates, but quite hard to see in Cartesian coordinates.

In Cartesian coordinates, an ellipse is $x = a \cos \theta, y = b \sin \theta$, and a hyperbola is $x = a \cosh \theta, y = b \sinh \theta$.  This suggests that an "intermediate function" between cos and cosh might produce a parabola.

Therefore: **Is there a continuous transformation between $\cos x$ to $\cosh x$?** [This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Transitions-from-sin-x-to-sinh-x-and-from-cos-x-to-cosh-x-at-x-0-They-are_fig1_259584622) claims there is, but the selection shown doesn't define it.

Since $$
\cos x = \frac {e^{ix} + e^{-ix}} 2 \\
\cosh x = \frac {e^{x} + e^{-x}} 2 \\
\cos x = \cosh ix \\
\cosh x = \cos ix \\
$$

it would follow that $$f(x;\theta) := \cos e^{i\theta}x$$ is exactly what we need, with $\theta = 0$ producing $\cos$ and $\theta = \frac \pi 2$ producing $\cosh$.

Questions:

1. Does there exist a $\theta$ such that the parametric equations $x = f(x; \theta), y = f(x + \frac {\pi} 2; \theta)$ produces a parabola?
2. What does $f$ with intermediate values of $\theta$ look like, both analytically and visually?
3. What do the parametric equations of intermediate values of $\theta$ produce?

Also: Mathematical plotting tools, such as Desmos and Wolfram Alpha, are quite powerful; is there a way I can use them to plot these equations?

Comment: The problem (I think) is that $f(x;\theta) = \cos e^{i\theta}x$ produces *complex*  (non-real) values for real $x$, unless $ e^{i\theta}$ is $\pm 1$ or $\pm i$.

Comment: The paper you cite is talking about a different kind of transition; namely, the piecewise-defined function $$f(x) = \begin{cases} \cos x & x \leq 0 \\ \cosh x & x \geq 0. \end{cases}$$  Taking that function along with its sine version won't trace out a parabola, it will trace out a circle when $x \leq 0$ and then switch to tracing out (part of) a hyperbola.

Comment: @MartinR Won't other values of $\theta$ cancel out the imaginary parts, like they do for $\theta = \frac \pi 2$?

Comment: Do the Jacobi elliptic functions answer your question?  See also my older answer [*here*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853766/analogies-between-tan-sec-and-sinh-cosh/2854410#2854410).

Comment: For pure geometric point of view and besides polar coordinates, I'd suggest using [*stereographic projection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereographic_projection) for **smooth** transition.